# PHP Late Static Binding error

Tags: php, oop, late-static-binding

I am trying to learn how to use LSB. I am trying to separate my common db methods into `class DatabaseObject` and extend it to all classes that will be using them. Common db methods being `find_by_id()`, `create()`, `delete()`, etc.

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

$found_personnel = Personnel::authenticate($username, $password);
```

### Classes

```
class DatabaseObject {


  public static function find_by_sql($sql="") {
    global $database;
    $result_set = $database->query($sql);
    $object_array = array();
    while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
        $object_array[] = self::instantiate($row);
    }

    return $object_array;
  }

  private static function instantiate($record) {
    $object = new self;

    foreach($record as $attribute=>$value){
        if ($object->has_attribute($attribute)) {
            $object->$attribute = $value;
        }
    }
    return $object;
  }

  private function has_attribute($attribute) {
    $object_vars = $this->attributes();

    return array_key_exists($attribute, $object_vars);
  }

  protected function attributes() {
    $attributes = array();

    //this static::$db_fields is where my problem is
    foreach(static::$db_fields as $field) {

      if(property_exists($this, $field)) {
        $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
      }
    }
    return $attributes;
  }
}

class Personnel extends DatabaseObject {
  protected static $table_name = "personnel";

  //this is the property I am trying to access in DatabaseObject
  protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'permissions');

public static function authenticate($username="", $password="") {
    global $database;
    $username = $database->escape_value($username);
    $password = $database->escape_value($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . self::$table_name . " ";
    $sql .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
    $sql .= "AND password = '{$password}' ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT 1";

    $result_array = parent::find_by_sql($sql);
    return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;

}
}
```

### The error I get:

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: DatabaseObject::$db_fields
```

Comment: Please show the code where you're calling `Personnel::attributes()`

Comment: Added all code that is involved. Could the problem be in `instantiate()`?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but using the 'global' keyword is a sign of doing it wrong, regardless of whether you're writing OOP code or procedural.  It's especially egregious in OOP as it blows apart encapsulation.  Look into dependency injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine for me. The error sounds like you have a `DatabaseObject` instance instead of a `Personnel` instance.

Comment: Your answer led me to the problem. Using instantiate() in DatabaseObject was creating a instance of the wrong thing. I will move all instantiate() methods to the classes extending DatabaseObject and change all `self::instantiate()` to `static::instantiate()`